# Download multiple files in flex

Tags: apache-flex

I am writing a file browsing application in flex. It displays a list of the available files, which could be of any file type, and allows the user to select files for download. I want users to be able to select multiple files at a time and hit a Download button only once.

However, I am running into issues with this. FileReference only allows you to download one file at a time. So I figure that I can just listen for the complete event, and then fire off the next download when the previous download completes. However, that does not work in flash 10+, as the FileReference download method needs to be user-initiated - that means it can't come from an event call stack.

Is there some other technique I am not seeing that would allow me to do this?

Comment: Best thing you're going to be able to do for a browser based app is--after the first file is downloaded--show a pop-up asking the user to download the second one.  Then the download will be user initiated.  As an alternate; you could launch multiple URLRequests.  You won't know when the download is complete, but at least you won't have the user initiated download problem.

Comment: Or put them all in an archive on the server side. Download that single file. And unzip on the client side.

Comment: It might not be quite what you're looking for but I DL files using a separate PHP script and just open a browser window for each. You could probably do this as often as you want.

Comment: @ethrbunny My suggestion, using multiple URLRequests, was that approach exactly.  Using URLRequests would be how to open a new browser window from the Flash Player.

Comment: @flextras - my mistake. I didn't read far enough into what you posted. Mea culpa.

Comment: The problem with URLRequests is that the browser will attempt to open the file if it knows how. I already have a different "Open" button that does just that. I am specifically looking for something that will start a download for each one of the files.

Comment: @Reboog711 Actually, I think you can know when it is complete. If you handle the complete event, the Event it passes to you has the FileReference in it. BTW, you'll also have to handle the ioError and cancel as well, to be certain when the file is done. Finally, you might run into a problem that most browsers present, which is limiting the number of concurrent sockets that can be open to a server at a time.

Comment: @PenguinLust URLRequest ( http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLRequest.html ) does not dispatch events; and I know of no way to listen for events from a navigateToURL call: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/package.html#navigateToURL%28%29 .